# Xamarin.Forms Windows 10 Universal Error "CS0103 InitializeComponent does not exist"

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, xamarin.forms, initializecomponent

I have a working Android Project with a .Droid-Solution and a SharedProject. I started the App on my phone and it works great. Now, I just added a blank Windows 10 Universal Solution and did the instructions here: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/windows/installation/universal/

Anyway... I did nothing else. Just followed the instructions and tryed to start the Windows 10 Universal app, but I get this error:

> "CS0103 C# The name 'InitializeComponent ' does not exist in the
>   current context."

I googled a few times, but didn't find something that helps.

I also tryed the example here: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Hanselman.Forms with the same error.

Does someone know this error with `Xamarin.Forms` and Windows 10 Universal Apps?

Comment: Where do you get this error? In the Win 10 project or in the common pcl project where most of your code lives? If it's the common project, then you need to make sure the appropriate build action and type are setup on your common xamarin xaml files and potentially run the custom tool manually. If you can confirm where the error is, I will reply with more detailed instructions.

Comment: I get the error in the SharedProject in every ContentPage. I am not absolutely sure, but maybe it's the same Bug like this one: [xamarin bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=36935). What exactly do you mean with "make sure the appropriate build action and type are setup on your common xamarin xaml files and potentially run the custom tool manuall"?

Comment: Okay, it looks like, it is the same bug. I found this [thread](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/54401/xamarin-forms-for-uwp-preview-now-available)

`@GaborNemeth said: Having the same problem as @"PrabhatGupta.2760" Cannot compile if any XAML page is coming from shared project. I created a sample project to reproduce this issue and attached it to https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=36935`

Answer (score 2):

Everytime you create a .XAML page in Xamarin.Forms, you are using partial class definitions in three different places.

Your actual .xaml file will have a Class="" attribute on the root element that defines the namespace and class name.
The actual root element type will define the base class that your new .xaml page is subclassing. By default, that would be ContentPage.

You also get a .xaml.cs file that is linked which contains a partial class definition as well. This is your code behind file, where you put page specific code, this is also where the InitializeComponent() call is called from the constructor.

This call serves to parse the xaml contents and fill out the references to all the views you gave ids to using x:name="something" in xaml.

InitializeComponent() is automatically generated by xamarin, it is part of the output of your project and it should get re-generated each time you edit your .xaml file.

In order for this to happen, in the properties of your .xaml file Build Action needs to be set to "Embedded Resource" and the Custom Tool needs to be set to "MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml"

Now, even with these values set correctly, there are bugs in Xamarin which can lead to the file not getting generated and you getting the error.

The absolute first thing to try when you get this error is to right click the .xaml file and click on "Run Custom Tool".
You only need to do this once, on ONE xaml file, the tool will automatically run for all the .xaml files in your project.

This is somethign that I have to do about once a day during my normal development and it started when i switched to VS 2015. Your mileage may warry.

Another very important thing to check is the BuildTargets in your .csproj file.

The way Xamarin is able to do it's thing is by specifying build actions that call into it's DLL that you get when you install the Xamarin.Forms nuget package. Sometimes the build actions import line get's messed up and this causes all sorts of problems.

Unload your .csproj and find the line that imports Xamarin.Forms.targets.
It should look something like this:

```
<Import Project="..\..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.0.0.6484\build\portable-win+net45+wp80+win81+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10+Xamarin.iOS10\Xamarin.Forms.targets" Condition="Exists('..\..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.2.0.0.6484\build\portable-win+net45+wp80+win81+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10+Xamarin.iOS10\Xamarin.Forms.targets')" />
```

make sure that the version in here matches the version of Xamarin.Forms from your packages.config file, then make sure that you can actually navigate to your project's root folder, and find the actual file the important line is referring to. Ie, packages\xamarin...\Xamarin.Forms.targets

A common thing to do is to delete everything from \packages\ and let nuget re-download everything on your next build. Just make sure the version in your .csproj import and the version in packages.config is the same.

If all of these are done, you should have a valid generated partial class that implements InitializeComponent() and the errors should dissapear.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an update to this:

1. New, clean Windows 10 Pro installation with all updates in a VM.
2. New, clean Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition installation with all options selected and all updates.
3. New project: Blank Xaml App (`Xamarin.Forms.Portable`) with nowt but generated code.

The project will not build as `InitializeComponent` in `App.xaml.cs` does not exist in the current context.

**Opinion:** this Xamarin add-on is a free add-on on top of a free product, but even so this kind of thing doesn't really inspire you to use it...